# CloudFormation commands list cwd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a list of 20 commands that I need to run, see code snippet below (shows commands 01 and 02)

```
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "configSets": {
                    "default": [
                        "install_packages"
                    ]
                },
                "install_packages": {
                    "commands": {
                        "01": {
                            "command": "sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip",
                            "cwd": "/home/ubuntu"
                        },
                        "02": {
                            "command": "sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv",
                            "cwd": "/home/ubuntu"
                        },
                        ...
```

As you can see, `cwd` there is repeated. I want to run all these commands from the home directory `/home/ubuntu`. Is there any way to do this without specifying it per command? What is the default cwd if it is not set here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, commands will allow multiple bash commands to be executed. You could try merging multiple commands into a single command argument - just copy the command from 02 and add it to the end of command from 01 with `&&` in between, i.e., `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip && sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv`

Comment: that's similar to what i ended up doing -- but i used \n. Thank you!